# Better way to write nested if-else statements

Tags: scala, if-statement, nested

What is a most Scala way to write the following piece of logic?

```
def collatzAlgorithm(target: Int): Int = {
    if (target % 2 == 0) {
      val new_target = target / 2
      if (new_target == 1) {
        new_target
      } else {
        if (new_target % 2 != 0) {
          new_target * 3 + 1
        } else {
          new_target
        }
      }
    } else {
      target
    }
  }
```

Thanks!!!!

Comment: This doesn't look like the "collatz algorithm", unless this is the function being iterated. And why are you checking for even results twice?

Comment: For `(1 to 10).map (collatzAlgo)` I get `Vector(1, 1, 3, 2, 5, 10, 7, 4, 9, 16)`, which shows, that all odd numbers return unchanged. So before optimising your algorithm, you should fix it. A slow or lengthy, but correct code, is better than a brief or fast one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code produces wrong results:

```
(1 to 10).map (collatzAlgorithm)
// Vector(1, 1, 3, 2, 5, 10, 7, 4, 9, 16)
```

All the odd values weren't changed. Here is a working solution:

```
def collatzAlgorithm (target: Int): Int = {
    if (target == 1) 1
    else target % 2 match {
        case 0 => target / 2 
        case 1 => target * 3 + 1
    }
}   

(1 to 10).map (collatzAlgorithm)
// Vector(1, 1, 10, 2, 16, 3, 22, 4, 28, 5)
```

You might consider a recursive algorithm, which calls the next step immediately:

```
def collatz (target: Int): Int = {
    if (target == 1) 1
    else target % 2 match {
        case 0 => collatz (target / 2)
        case 1 => collatz (target * 3 + 1)
    }
}
```

Which works fine for small values:

```
(1 to 10).map (collatz)
// Vector(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

However - for bigger and many inputs, the same sequence is calculated again and again, so a resolution should work with some kind of memoization to avoid this inefficiency.

Answer (score 1):

It's not so much about the scala way as it is about needing to simplify and flatten your nesting.  I would refactor it to:

```
val newTarget = target / 2
if (newTarget % 2 == 0) {
  newTarget
} else if (newTarget != 1) {
  newTarget * 3 + 1
} else {
  1
}
```

However, it's hard to tell if this actually does what you think it does, because you're confusingly trying to work a step ahead.  I would write a collatz sequence something like:

```
Iterator.iterate(n){n => if (n % 2 == 0) n / 2 else 3 * n + 1}.takeWhile{_ != 1}
```

This ends at `2`, but you could add `++ Iterator(1)` if you really need it to end at `1`.